# How can I emit a redstone signal when a player eats a golden apple?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I need it so that when a player eats an golden apple, the command block sends a redstone signal. Is there a command for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create food allergies in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312941/is-it-possible-to-create-food-allergies-in-minecraft)

Comment: Are you playing on Java or bedrock?

Comment: Btw we probably shouldnt close as duplicate until the version has been given

Comment: First of all, you [shouldn't be using redstone for this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235448/why-remove-redstone-dust-from-my-command-block-contraptions). That's a direct path to the land of bugs.

Comment: @MBraedley do keep in mind that only applies to java

Comment: @Penguin no, you are absolutely wrong about that. It doesn't matter which version you're playing, redstone and commands don't mix.

Comment: @MBraedley, no you are absolutely wrong about that. Unless we just don't wanna make certain things, that's wrong. How can I do a not-gate without redstone? What about other complex gates? [This has been a point of discussion before, the other person deleted their comments so it's a one-sided conversation but I haven't seen any alternatives](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/377646/258509)

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/312941/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-player-consuming-food-items), in that you want to detect when a player eats a specific food item on the server. @AjaxGb has offered this solution:

> You can make scoreboard objectives of type `minecraft.used:minecraft.<food item name>`, for example:
>
> `/scoreboard objectives add eatBread minecraft.used:minecraft.bread`

In your case, you want to detect when a player eats a **golden apple**, so you would do something like:

```
/scoreboard objectives add eatGoldenApple minecraft.used:minecraft.golden_apple
```

However, you also said that you'd want to emit a *redstone signal.* As mentioned in the comments, and in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235448/why-remove-redstone-dust-from-my-command-block-contraptions), that's probably not the ideal thing to do. But you could rig up a [redstone comparator](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Comparator) so that it emits a redstone signal on golden apple eating detection.

I'm not sure what version you are playing on, so I'll offer you some options depending on your Minecraft version.

*Java Edition, pre-1.14:*

```
/scoreboard players test @p eatGoldenApple 1
```

[*Bedrock Edition:*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/368821/minecraft-bedrock-testfor-command)

```
/testfor @p[scores={eatGoldenApple=..1}]
```

[*Java Edition, post-1.14:*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352405/finding-a-replacement-for-the-scoreboard-player-test)

```
/execute if score  (Player)   eatGoldenApple   matches 1
```